# Why it uses extra line "sumOf( )" in the following func - Swift?

Tags: swift

The following `func` is right. But I don't understand why it uses extra line `sumOf ( )`? Also what's the meaning of "`Int...`" ?
Someone has any clue?

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}

sumOf()
sumOf(42, 597, 12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `sumOf()` is demonstrating that you can call the function with no arguments at all.

Answer (score 0):

Both the class to `sumOf` are "unnecessary" for the function itself. It's just showing the usage.

`Int...` is a variadic parameter

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type.
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html